# ADB2C Password Reset Fails

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

We use ADB2C custom policies with MFA enabled. Currently our password reset is failing. When a user tries to reset password we get the "Account could not be found for the Provided UserID" error

[image]

If I manually copy the Alternate email field to the Email field on the portal and try to reset my password it works. My hypothesis is that something in the custom policy chain is causing the email claim to not persist correctly on sign up? (Alternate email seems to persist fine)

[image]

In our custom policy I  do see the following in the extensions policy:

```
<PersistedClaimClaimTypeReferenceId="email"PartnerClaimType="strongAuthenticationEmailAddress"/>
```

in the UserWriteUsingLogonName technical profile, which is what's invoked by the Self Asserted 'LocalAccountSignUpWithLogonName' technical profile (corresponds to a user signing up).

This is a snippet of the TrustFrameWorkExtensions File
[image]

Here are snippets from the TrustFrameworkBase file.
[image]

[image]

Here is the self-asserted technical profile for Sign In and Sign Up

[image]
[image]

[image]

We use the default password reset B2C_1_PasswordReset
[image]

Comment: Post the self asserted technical profile which asks for the email at sign up.

Comment: Jas Suri, I updated my post. Can you please let me know if that is what you were looking for?

Comment: Looks ok, see my [sample](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/blob/master/policies/username-signup-or-signin/policy/Username_TrustFrameworkExtensions.xml). Post the xml snippets of password reset doing the lookup for the strongAuthEmail and comparing to the user entered email.

Comment: Jas Suri, I added the password reset xml to my post above. I am not seeing strongAuthEmail anywhere in the password reset flow.

Comment: your password reset flow is a user flow, so you wont see all the details in it. But it should be using strongAuthEmail attribute to do the match. What version of user flow are you using? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/user-flow-versions

Comment: We are using Version 1

Comment: It’s probably the reason, I’ve never tested that with v1 (deprecated). V2 user flow will work or try my sample instead from [here](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/username-or-email) which will work.